# UItableview Could not cast value of type Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, parsing

So I have Two Classes one define mines my cell: ListTableViewCell, and the other one defines my table:ListTableView. I am trying to pull data from a parse server to display as the two uilabels in the cell. I am running into an error at this line of code.

```
 self.Data = array as! NSMutableArray
```

It is giving me the error "Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray' (0x107bc36b8) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x105f7fcd0)."

Any suggestions to fix this.

```
class ListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var team: UILabel!

}
```

This is the tableview.

```
class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController{

var Data: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

func loadData(){

    Data.removeAllObjects()

    let findData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "data")
    findData.getFirstObjectInBackground() {(objects: PFObject?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if !(error != nil){
            for object in [objects] as [PFObject?]{
                self.Data.add(object)
            }
        }
        let array:NSArray = self.Data.reversed() as NSArray
        self.Data = array as! NSMutableArray
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.loadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Data.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:ListTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listCell", for: indexPath) as! ListTableViewCell

    let listData:PFObject = self.Data.object(at: indexPath.row) as! PFObject

    cell.name.text = listData.object(forKey: "name") as? String


    return cell
}


}
```

EDIT***

Changed:

```
   var Data = [PFObject]()


   Data.removeAllObjects() which I changed to Data.removeAll()
   self.Data.add(object) which I changed to aelf.Data.append(object)
```

Completely removed this

```
   let array:NSArray = self.Data.reversed() as NSArray
   self.Data = array as! NSMutableArray
```

This last error I can't fix is this one

```
let listData:PFObject = self.Data.object(at: indexPath.row) as! PFObject
```

It is throwing an error saying [PFObject] has no member object.

Comment: What if you use Swift data types instead of NS* things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're having the same issue I had when I started with Swift: You're still using Obj-C arrays. Try using [Swift Arrays!](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

EDIT: To answer your recently edited question, you are referencing objects incorrectly.

What it means when it tells you `has no member object` is that you are saying:

```
let listData:PFObject = self.Data.object(at: indexPath.row) as! PFObject
```

This part specifically: `self.data.object(at: indexPath.row)`

If you reference the link I shared above, you will see that you reference objects in your swift arrays as such:

```
let listData:PFObject = self.Data[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
```

Comment: I suppose most people don't realize that using NSArray was necessary in Objective-C because, well, C arrays are a pain, but this is Swift, we have real arrays now, no need to use NS* anymore. :)

Comment: Ok so I tried many different attempts at swift arrays ad it would throw errors in other places after that. Do you have any specific suggestions?

Comment: @JaradKears can't help you if I don't know what the errors are or where they're being thrown.

Comment: Ok so i posted an edit on the original code. Thanks for the help